# Adapt card width to fit un-overflowed content text

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make an account popup using a Semantic UI card, inspired from their [cards example](http://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html#cards):

```
<div class="ui compact raised card">
  <div class="content">
    <img class="ui right floated image" src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="header">Foo Bar</div>
    <div class="meta">foo.bar@example.com</div>
    <div class="ui primary basic profile button">
      <i class="fitted user icon"></i>
      My Account
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <a href="#"><i class="ui fitted sign out icon"></i>Sign Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Runnable example:

Available on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Franky47/pen/gwYLod), with several length of header/meta to visualize the layout issues.

### The problem:

Longer contents of `headers`/`meta` overflow.

### What I'd like:

I'd like the card width to expand to keep the layout intact instead. What would I need to change in my CSS and/or HTML structure to do that ?

I found that using `display: table` on the card allows longer text to expand the card width, but only when there is no `right floated` image. The presence of the image still wraps the text.

In CodePen, the CSS selector `.ui.compact.card` contains ideal target widths for the card, that one can apply to see the desired effect.

### Requirements:

- CSS/CSS3 only, this should not be a Javascript job (ie: no jQuery).
- Browser compatibility: IE9+

Comment: so you want to prevent the overflow and let the cards have the same width?

Comment: I want to prevent the overflow, but each card should only take as much horizontal space as actually needed, therefore they should not have the same width.

Comment: but in the codepen when you have `display: table` and it is not overflowing right?

Comment: It does not overflow out of the card anymore, but the header wraps around the image, and the email is pushed down after the image. `display: table` helps long text increase the size of the card, but does not take the size of the image into account (as it's floating).

Comment: I have updated the CodePen to add a checkbox that switches from current state to what it should look like (with ideal width manually set per example), that should be more clear. The image would get pushed to the right, and the card width would increase as the name/email length grows.

Comment: you have to maintain a fixed width for all cards or use class <div class="ui fluid raised card">